# nginx on Windows always return text/plain

Tags: windows, nginx

I'm using nginx 1.6.2 on Windows (development machine) and I have an issue where it will always return a `text/plain` value for the `Content-Type` header of any file. This is a problem because then browsers won't render CSS, compute JS, etc.

By default I had no default nginx.config file (unlike on Linux) so I had to build it from scratch while keeping it minimal. Normally my issue is solved by including `etc/nginx/mime.types` so I copy/pasted that file from a CentOS server I have. But it doesn't seem to have any effect. I tried to purposedly make the include path wrong, and that triggered an error, so I think it's actually parsed correctly when I make it correct.

So I have absolutely no idea why nginx keeps returning text/plain for every single fine I have.

This is my nginx.conf file:

```
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include     D:/dev/nginx/mime.types;

    expires off;

    default_type application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  D:/dev/nginx/logs/access.log  main;
    error_log  D:/dev/nginx/logs/error.log;


    upstream backend  {
        server localhost:62755;
    }

    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name localhost;

        client_body_temp_path      D:/dev/nginx/client_body_temp;
        proxy_temp_path            D:/dev/nginx/proxy_temp;


        location / {
            root D:/dev/frontend/src;
            index index.html;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue was that even when CTLR+C'ing, the nginx instance wasn't killed. I've found this by going into the Task Manager. Apparently old instances kept an old version of the config running, and were the first to intercept the requests, so even when changing nginx.conf, the changes weren't applied.

Killing all the processed made it so my latest config, the one where I included mime.types, was taken into account and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Even if no one else replied, you were able to fix the issue, so please mark it as the accepted solution. It helps direct other users to your response and to mark the question as "answered".

Comment: Sorry, it's now done.